# What does `end` mean in a Fortran read statement?

Tags: fortran

What does the `end=` in this code snippet mean?

```
read(portNum, 100, end =900) readline
```

P.S. I already tried Google to find this, without luck.

Comment: @francescalus I'm not opposed to you editing it back.

Comment: @user3600286 `read` is not a function in Fortran, you can easily see that from the different syntax, but the more important thing is that it behaves very differently from a function.

Comment: Otherwise, in my Google it is described in the very first link after searching "fortran read end".

Answer (score 3):

@user3600286:

Quoted directly from [this pdf](http://www.tomzap.com/notes/Fortran/Fortran.pdf):

> END=900 instructs the program to go to heading 900 in the event all records have been read

The 'readline' at the end appears to be a string variable (would have been defined earlier in the program) that temporarily holds each line read in from the file.