# How to know that we reached EOF in Fortran 77?

Tags: io, fortran, readfile, fortran77

So let's assume that I have the following subroutine:

```
         subroutine foo(a_date)
         character*10 dummy, a_date
         open(unit=1,file='ifile.txt',status='old')
         read(1, 100) dummy
   100   format(A10)
         a_date = dummy
         return
         end
```

which only reads a line from the file. But I want to read all the lines recursively. So when I call the subroutine recursively in my main procedure, I get an error after reaching EOF. So is there a way to prevent it so that the program knows when I reach EOF? 
Basically, I want to be able to know when I reach EOF.

Comment: Use `END=`. I would be surprised if we didn't have a duplicate. Or ditch the super-obsolete Fortran 77 and use `iostat=` which is "only" 29 years old. I would seriously suggest learning modern Fortran, it is 2019, not 1979.

Comment: Well, I was asked to use Fortran 77 specifically, therefore I have no choice. Can you elaborate more on `END=`? Thanks! @VladimirF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two methods. I refuse to teach the obsolete Fortran 77 which shouldn't have been used or taught in 25 years+, but the first method should work in any version of Fortran from 77 onwards

Method 1:

```
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/stackoverflow $ cat data.dat 
1
2
3
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/stackoverflow $ cat end.f90
Program eof
  Implicit None
  Integer :: data
  Open( 10, file = 'data.dat' )
  Do
     Read( 10, *, End = 1 ) data
     Write( *, * ) data
  End Do
1 Write( *, * ) 'Hit EOF'
End Program eof
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/stackoverflow $ gfortran -std=f2003 -Wall -Wextra -O -fcheck=all end.f90 
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/stackoverflow $ ./a.out
           1
           2
           3
 Hit EOF
```

Method 2:

This needs F2003, but that's what you should be using these days

```
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/stackoverflow $ cat data.dat 
1
2
3
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/stackoverflow $ cat end2.f90
Program eof
  Use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only : iostat_end
  Implicit None
  Integer :: data, error
  Open( 10, file = 'data.dat' )
  Do
     Read( 10, *, iostat = error ) data
     Select Case( error )
     Case( 0 )
        Write( *, * ) data
     Case( iostat_end )
        Exit
     Case Default
        Write( *, * ) 'Error in reading file'
        Stop
     End Select
  End Do
  Write( *, * ) 'Hit EOF'
End Program eof
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/stackoverflow $ gfortran -std=f2003 -Wall -Wextra -O -fcheck=all end2.f90 
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/stackoverflow $ ./a.out
           1
           2
           3
 Hit EOF
```

Comment: That was intuitive. You should say that to my professor actually about the obsoleteness of f77 :D. I have one slight question though, since we have to use `end=` like a `goto` statement, we cannot go to the main procedure, right? Because `goto` can only go to a statement below? Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, but if it is that the end statement is effectively a goto statement which must branch to a labelled statement then yes that is the case - you cannot call a subroutine using End=. And teaching F77 is something that really annoys me, it perpetuates bad practice and through that killing Fortran despite it still being (IMO) the best language for much numerical work.

Answer (score 2):

In Fortran 77 you use the [`END=label` specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451065/what-does-end-mean-in-a-fortran-read-statement), it instructs the program to go the given `label` when the end of file condition is triggered. Basically it works like a `GO TO` statement triggered by the `READ` statement.

In Fortran 90 and later you can also use  the `IOSTAT=integer_var` specifier. If an error condition happened, `integer_var` will be positive, if an `end-of-record` (EOR) or `end-of-file` (EOF) condition happened, the value will be negative.

In Fortran 2003, one can find out the actual values for the EOR and EOF conditions in named constant as shown in the answer by Ian Bush.