# Error related to EOF command in fortran code

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am a beginner to Fortran and am trying to compile a Fixed-Term Fortran Code using gfortran. I got a bunch of errors, which I could fix them. However, there is an Error related to "EOF" which I could not solve it. Is there any way to fix this problem? (The two "EOF" lines are lines 40 and 121.)

```
 37         OPEN(4,FILE="ABCE.Pn")
 38 
 39         OPEN(5,FILE="../sta.txt")
 40         DO WHILE (.not.EOF(5))
 41                 N=N+1
 42                 READ(5,*)STA(N)%COD,STA(N)%NAME,STA(N)%LAT,
 43      $          STA(N)%LON,STA(N)%H
 44         ENDDO
 45         NSTA=N
 46         CLOSE(5)`

 ......

121         DO WHILE (.not.EOF(1))
122                 READ(1,'(A60)',ERR=999) TIT
123 C               IF(IYEAR.GE.2008.OR. 
      (IYEAR.EQ.2007.AND.MONTH.GE.11)) 
124 C     $         TIT=TIT(2:60)
125                 IF(TIT(1:60).EQ.'')THEN         ! NEW EARTHQUAKE`
```

The error:

```
      DO WHILE (.not.EOF(5))                                            
                     1
Error: Operand of .not. operator at (1) is REAL(4)
ReadP2Pn.for:121.21:

      DO WHILE (.not.EOF(1))                                            
                     1
Error: Operand of .not. operator at (1) is REAL(4)
```

Comment: Most likely somebody has been using a non-standard extension, that is the EOF function, and the compiler you are now using doesn't support it - a nice example of why people whould stick to what the standard says. I strongly suspect the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54399425/how-to-know-that-we-reached-eof-in-fortran-77/54399767#54399767 will be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EOF(5) is non-standard. You should check for EOF in the read statement (which sadly looks like a goto) :

```
 40         DO WHILE (.true.)
 41                 N=N+1
 42                 READ(5,*,end=990)STA(N)%COD,STA(N)%NAME,STA(N)%LAT,
 43      $          STA(N)%LON,STA(N)%H
 44         ENDDO
 45    990  NSTA=N
```

Comment: There are other ways which avoid the line label - see the answer linked in the comment above

Comment: Oh, yeah. iostat. I've used that in original code, but not in legacy code (I guess since the legacy code was already riddled with line labels). Thanks.

Comment: I used Intel Fortran Compiler instead of gfortran to compile the code and it worked well. Thanks so much for your answers.