# Error: Operand of .not. operator at (1) is REAL(4)

Tags: fortran

My code is causing a compile-time error

```
Parameter(nx=121,ny=81) 

Real u(nx,ny),v(nx,ny),p(nx,ny)
    
        open(1,file='u-component.txt')
            Read(1,*)
        open(2,file='v-component.txt')
             Read(2,*)
        open(3,file='Pressure.txt')
             Read(3,*)
        open(11,file='windVN.TXT')
        
        irec =0
        
        DO while(.not.eof(1))
       
        jj=irec

        
        do 1 j=1,ny
            Do 2 i=1,nx 
                    read(1,*) a1,a2,a3,a4,u(i,j)
                    read(2,*) a1,a2,a3,a4,v(i,j)
                    read(3,*) a1,a2,a3,p(i,j)

            2 continue 
        1 continue

    
        write(11,*)
        write(11,*) '"tstep"', jj, '"item"',1, '"layer"', 0

    do 3 j=1,ny
                 write(11,101) (u(i,j),i=1,nx)
       3 continue
        
        write(11,*)
        write(11,*) '"tstep"', jj, '"item"',2, '"layer"', 0     

    do 4 j=1,ny
                write(11,101) (v(i,j),i=1,nx)
       4 continue           
    
        write(11,*)
        write(11,*) '"tstep"', jj, '"item"',3, '"layer"', 0

    do 5 j=1,ny
                write(11,102) (p(i,j)/1000,i=1,nx)
       5 continue
    
        
         irec = irec +1
    end do 
         Write(*,*)  irec,'  Step', irec*3, '  h'

    101 format(121f9.2)
    102 format(121f9.2)
        Pause
        Stop
 END
```

```
DO while(.not.eof(1))
                      1
Error: Operand of .not. operator at (1) is REAL(4)

Error: Last command making (build\changeWdata_col.o) returned a bad status

Error: Make execution terminated
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You should always use `IMPLICIT NONE`. No exceptions. And really always, when you have some error in your code.

`eof()` is not a standard Fortran procedure. Some compiler may offer it as an extension, but other compilers do not have to. Fortran have other means using the `end=` and `iostat=` specifiers in the I/O statements.

That means, you can use

```
read(1,*,end=some_label) a1,a2,a3,a4,u(i,j)
```

or

```
read(1,*,iostat=some_integer_variable) a1,a2,a3,a4,u(i,j)
```

The meaning differs, please consult a textbook or tutorial or other StackOverflow questions and answers like [How to know that we reached EOF in Fortran 77?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54399425/how-to-know-that-we-reached-eof-in-fortran-77)  or some oriented to a more modern Fortran.

Also, avoid unit numbers below 10, they are often already pre-connected for special purposes. Most often 0,5 and 6, but other numbers could be as well.